# Custom add to cart link not adding the product to cart. The cart is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that allows me to add a custom 'Buy the Original' link on any product page. The function is triggered by an html link which calls the product by ID. It redirects to the cart page properly but the product does not add to the page. The cart comes up empty.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_buy_original_link' );

function custom_buy_original_link() {
    global $product;

    // Check if the current page is a product page
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) . '?add-to-cart=' . urlencode($product_name) . '">Buy the Original</a>';
    }
}
```

I was expecting the product called by ID to be added to the cart:

```html
<a href="website/cart/?product_id=1232">Buy the original: $2,100</a>
```

Comment: All versions I see suggested here, https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/ (first Google hit on the issue), use the parameter name `add-to-cart` for the product ID, and also include a `quantity` parameter.

Comment: That worked. It was missing the quantity! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer thanks to CBroe, is to add the quantity, as seen here: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

Comment: Please add the relevant contents to your answer, as links are susceptible to [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).